# Why is my assignment to cv::Mat iterator not working?

Tags: c++, opencv, iterator

### Update

Thanks for all of the feedback. I was being an idiot as the answers quite patiently point out: the problem lies in the value of mParams.amount which is not being correctly updated by the interface. I have no idea why I didn't check this explicitly or notice it in the debugger. Just one of those days.

The reason I provided the whole function was because I was completely perplexed as to why things weren't working and was concerned there might have been some kind of contextual issue surrounding the iterator - but as with above it just needed a bit more common sense.

---

### Original question

I'm attempting to implement a contrast filter over a four channel normalized float cv::Mat using an iterator as follows:

```
void FilterDepthContrast::process(cv::Mat& data)
{
    typedef cv::Vec<float, 4> V;
    V mid = V(.5, .5, .5, .5);
    for (auto v=data.begin<V>(); v!=data.end<V>(); ++v)
    {
        V distanceFromMiddle = *v - mid;
        cout << "v before " << *v << endl;
        *v = mid + mParams.amount * distanceFromMiddle;
        cout << "added on " << (mParams.amount * distanceFromMiddle) << endl;
        cout << "v after " << *v << endl;
    }
}
```

However, the assignment to *v does not seem to be working. Here is what is printed:

```
v before (0.94902,0.960784,0.929412,0.211765)
added on (0.44902,0.460784,0.429412,-0.288235)
v after (0.94902,0.960784,0.929412,0.211765)
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong with this iterator and how to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you print `mid + mParams.amount * distanceFromMiddle;`? If `mParams.amount` is `1` then you have `*v = *v`.

Comment: There's some extraneous code. You don't need the loop, or the function to demonstrate your problem. Create a simpler example, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the iterator.
With your formula, you will get the result as you printed.

See how :

```
V mid = V(.5, .5, .5, .5);
```

As printed initial *v = 0.94902,0.960784,0.929412,0.211765

Apply

```
V distanceFromMiddle = *v - mid;
```

distanceFromMiddle = (0.44902,0.460784,0.429412,-0.288235)

Also as printed,
(mParams.amount * distanceFromMiddle) = (0.44902,0.460784,0.429412,-0.288235)

Now apply

```
*v = mid + mParams.amount * distanceFromMiddle;
```

(.5, .5, .5, .5) + (0.44902,0.460784,0.429412,-0.288235) = (0.94902,0.960784,0.929412,0.211765)

I think the problem comes because mParams.amount = 1.

Comment: Thanks, you are both completely right - please see my comment made to the original question

Answer (score 2):

You have `V = (0.94902,0.960784,0.929412,0.211765)`

and `mid = (.5, .5, .5, .5)`

so `distanceFromMiddle = V - mid = (0.44902,0.460784,0.429412,-0.288235)`

but your output from `cout << "added on " << (mParams.amount * distanceFromMiddle) << endl;`
is the same so  `distanceFromMiddle== (mParams.amount * distanceFromMiddle)`

Conclusion : `mParams.amount == 1`

Comment: Yes, yes, painfully obvious really. Thank you!